# Process.GetProcessById() throwing ArgumentException " Process Not Running " on all thread ids/process ids

Tags: c#, exception, process, pinvoke, pid

No matter which one of these i try to use, `Process.GetProcessById().ProcessName` throws an exception stating ALL of the processes are not running.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr ProcessId);

            for (int x = 0; x < listBox1.Items.Count; x++)
            {
                IntPtr y = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[x].ToString()));
                uint processID = 0;
                int procID = Convert.ToInt32(GetWindowThreadProcessId(y, out processID));
                //int procID = Convert.ToInt32(GetWindowThreadProcessId(y, IntPtr.Zero);
                //listBox2.Items.Add(procID);
                listBox2.Items.Add(Process.GetProcessById(procID).ProcessName);
            }
```

Comment: use with EnumWindows and/or EnumChildWindows http://pinvoke.net

Comment: How do you fill listBox1?

Comment: Arent you suppose to use `processID` instead of the return value?

Comment: yes, thank you.. put that as an answer and i'll hit solved

Comment: Rubbish API tho, isn't it? Of couse you would assume it returned the thing it says it's doing. I bet this happens a lot.

Comment: any solution about it ?